# Может ли clickhouse-client делать INSERT "транзакционно", или все или ничего (insert из csv файла)

Tags: clickhouse

есть файл csv (большой 2000000 строк).
Вызываю clickhouse-client, чтоб он вставил строки из файла в БД.
Если в какой-то строке "неправильный" формат данных, то операция прерывается с ошибкой.
Но часть данных успевает вставиться в БД.
Как можно попросить clickhouse работать транзакционно? Или все вставить или ничего.
Или можно ли получить от clickhouse-client ответ сколько вставилось строк?

```
clickhouse-client -q "INSERT INTO my_table FORMAT CSVWithNames SETTINGS input_format_skip_unknown_fields=1" --date_time_input_format=best_effort -h 127.0.0.1 --password pass < file.csv
```